# "Sql azure" can't login after backup/restore

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

On azure i have an app service (iis) connected to an sql server app instance.

I scheduled a backup of the app service configured to backup also the related sql server.

After the restore of the backup, i can't login with a user not admin (Login failed for user).

Thanks

Comment: Try to connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio. Verify the connection string and the Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection string is valid and update the database connection string if necessary. Use admin user in connection string.

Try to connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio.

Examine Web.Config and update connection information.

Make sure you have followed the steps described on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-restore#restore-an-app-from-an-existing-backup) documentation.